# MailGun Laravel - Cant send to gmail

Tags: laravel-5, mailgun

I have mailgun setup and working with my custom domain name, as in, I can send test emails to me@mydomain.com but when I try to send to gmail I get the following error.

```
    ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
    Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.com/messages.mime` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
    {
    "message": "Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the act (truncated...)
```

My mailgun account is setup to work with my domain name correctly and my custom email address doesn't match my site domain name and mail gets delivered to it from mailgun no problems...

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
    MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mydomain.com
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@mydomain.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=ljhasdlkfhklahsdfklhklasdhflkhasdlkfhkhasdkflh
    MAILGUN_SECRET=key-asdflkhjaklsdfkljaslkdfjlkjasdfkj
    MAIL_FROM=postmaster@mydomain.com
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Its weird that when trying to send to a gmail address it gives tells me I need to activate my mailgun account but when sending to a custom domain name address its works perfectly, anyone have any ideas.. Here is the function I am using to send the emails

```
    Mail::send('emails.recontact', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) use ($request){

        $message->from( 'me@mysite.ie', $request->input('name') );

        $message->to('myname@gmail.com');

        $message->subject("Website Enquiry");

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to activate you account.

Please login to your mailgun account and make sure there is no a yellow message on the top of the screen that said:

"Please activate your account to start sending emails. We sent an activation email to {your_email}. Resend activation. Update email address."

This solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on mailgun but i faced different problem when recipient reply mail stores instead of delivered